# How do I install release build of sorbet?

Tags: sorbet

I install sorbet according to their instructions on the GitHub README:

> Install the dependencies
>
> `brew install bazel autoconf coreutils parallel Clone this repository`
>
> git clone https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet.git cd sorbet Build Sorbet
>
> `bazel build //main:sorbet --config=dbg`

But when I run it, I got the following:

```
$ bazel-bin/main/sorbet -e "42 + 2"
 Hey there! Heads up that this is not a release build of sorbet.
Release builds are faster and more well-supported by the Sorbet team.
Check out the README to learn how to build Sorbet in release mode.
To forcibly silence this error, either pass --silence-dev-message,
or set SORBET_SILENCE_DEV_MESSAGE=1 in your shell environment.

No errors! Great job.
```

I want to install the release build because I want to use a well supported sorbet so I go to their GitHub README again and see this:

> `--config=release-mac` and `--config=release-linux` Exact release configuration that we ship to our users.

So I run this:

bazel build //main:sorbet --config=dbg --config=release-mac

But it end up with this line:

```
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I tried this too:

```
bazel build //main:sorbet --config=release-mac
```

But it end up with this line too:

```
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

What should I do to install a release build of Sorbet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readme file in Sorbet repo describes how to compile Sorbet, not how to install an existing release.

To install existing release, follow guide at https://sorbet.org/docs/adopting

If you insist on compiling release from sources on your own, in order to help you, we'll need more build log, as you didn't include messages that told what specifically went wrong.

Now, using a crystall ball, I would guess that you're attempting to compile Sorbet on OS X Mojave that doesn't ship with system C++ headers and thus build fails to find `math.h` or `stdio.h`. Sorbet Readme contains instructions for how to install headers in the Readme: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet#common-compilation-errors.

Comment: I I created a new rails project using ruby 2.6.3 and I added the 2 lines into Gemfile (`gem 'sorbet', :group => :development` and `gem 'sorbet-runtime'`), then I run `bundle install` but I got `Could not find sorbet-static-0.4.4389-universal-darwin-14 in any of the sources`. Do you know why? @user537862

Comment: Are you sure you're using public RubyGems, not some internal mirror?

Comment: I was having the same problem, using public RubyGems yesterday, but today it works.